# Any disadvantages in reusing the jobs for multiple projects by passing parameters from the preceding job

Tags: jenkins, jobs, reusability

Could anyone please help to see if there are any potential disadvantages with this approach

In our scenario, where we have multiple projects which get added frequently, we wanted to minimize the effort of creating jobs, so we thought of reusing the jobs with different parameters. And we are using pipelines and parameterized trigger plugins in order to achieve this dependency between the jobs. Here in our case, we have startup, build, test and deploy jobs setup as a pipeline. Startup job is to just accept parameters to trigger the down line jobs such as source code location and common workspace for subsequent jobs. For every new project, we are adding a new startup job with different parameters and triggering the build job which is common for all the projects with parameters being different.

Appreciate if anyone can suggest potential disadvantages that we might encounter down the line with this approach.

Thanks in advance,
Santosh

Comment: The main problem is that all your build history will all be combined for all your jobs running the same plan.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much of Jenkins you use for reporting/tracking.

For example, having the same **build job** from different SCM locations (through a parameter) is perfectly fine, however as the parameters change, it will be nuking the previous checkout and checking out the new SCM location.

- First, this will increase checkout, and therefore build time (but it will save on diskspace)
- Second, you could not select a build in Jenkins and click "show changes", as it can't keep "changes" when a new checkout is performed

Another example, having the same **deploy job**, with different parameters for the artifacts. I've had that, and went away from using it. Reason: when I was asked "when was the last time build was deployed to environment A?" I had to manually comb through each build history to find one that matched with parameter "A". Don't even bother trying to explain ^that^ to someone else on your team. Now, I have a "deploy job to environment A", "deploy job to environment B", and so on, and tracking history of deployments is easy as pie.

So, if your Jenkins runs autonomously, and no one (including you) ever logs in to the UI, then by all means, use single jobs. But if people use Jenkins to tracking, and review of console logs, having more granular jobs really helps

Coincidentally, if you have more granular jobs, you won't be having the issues this user is having: [Jenkins: Filter build history by label or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768722/jenkins-filter-build-history-by-label-or-parameter)